# Addition of php associative array values not working

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to add a bunch of array values together, keeping the ID value....
I thought I could use a basic foreach with a `+=` operator, but it's not working out.

Here are my arrays:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [246] => Array(
                    [amount] => 2
                )    
        )    
)
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [245] => Array(
                    [amount] => 1
                )    
        )    
)
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [243] => Array(
                    [amount] => 2
                )    
        )    
)
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [245] => Array(
                    [amount] => 1
                )    
        )    
)

Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [243] => Array(
                    [amount] => 2
                )    
        )    
)
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
array(
'243' => '4',
'245' => '2',
'246' => '2',
);
```

And here's what I was attempting:

```
$sumArray = array();

foreach ($orgArray[0] as $k=>$subArray) {

    foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {

        $sumArray[$k]+=$value;
    }
}
```

Here is what I'm getting:

```
Array
(
    [243] => 2
)
```

Comment: Your structure actually looks like several individual arrays, not one multidimensional array, and your output supports that. Do you have these as an array of arrays?  Please post the code where your arrays are stored or created. Use `var_export($orgArray)`

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to modify your `foreach` loops as you're trying to set `$key` which is the index of the arrays which for the example above would be `0,1,2,3...etc` **not** `246,245,243...etc` as you expect.

This is what you want.

```
$orgArray = [
    [246 => ['amount' => 2]],
    [245 => ['amount' => 1]],
    [243 => ['amount' => 2]],
    [245 => ['amount' => 1]],
    [243 => ['amount' => 2]],
];

$sumArray = array();

foreach ($orgArray as $k => $subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $id => $item) {
        if (!isset($sumArray[$id])) {
            $sumArray[$id] = 0;
        }
        $sumArray[$id] += $item['amount'];
    }
}
```

<sup>**Note:** *The above `[]` array identifier is assuming you're using the correct php version that allows it, otherwise you'd have to change them to `array()`*</sup>

Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [246] => 2
    [245] => 2
    [243] => 4
)
```

As expected.

[**`EXAMPLE`**](https://eval.in/240023)

Comment: Although it seems like it should be, I'm not convinced that is actually the structure of the input array. Notice that the `print_r()` output shown doesn't have any `[]` index preceding each `Array` declaration so something is strange here.

Comment: I think it might be multidimensional, with the OP just copying the content and not the `Array()` wrapper that should've been included. But it is weird, since he's trying to access it via `$orgArray[0]`?

Comment: I take the `$orgArray[0]` to be correctly attempting to access any one of those sub-arrays, but am not sure all those sub-arrays are actually parts of a whole larger structure. Lack of index on them makes them look like individual arrays which were `print_r()`'d in a loop.

Comment: I'm actually with you on that one @MichaelBerkowski ! This is one weird question, I think my assumption on associativeness was wrong!